# Can I ask a "what tech to use"-question if I have specific desired features in mind?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The question I'd like to ask (no, did not ask it yet) is regarding searching a technlogy which:

- Lets you program with OOP (*actual* OOP, i.e. code with abstraction, classes, methods, inheritance, information hiding, and stuff defined to be in OOP theory).
- Has an assets management system (images, sounds, particles, interacting objects and, perhaps, even level editor).
- Is actually maintained (an active community, at least one release each year).
- Has Android/iPhone deployment options (included or by plug-ins).

This question has a specific description and has no place for subjectivity (no place for *best* technologies here). Is somehow this question suitable as Community Wiki?

Comment: When you say "regarding searching a technology" do you mean you're looking for recommendations for some technology that fit those provided criteria? That's not (currently) a thing we consider on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Found it.

*Searching a technology* is on-topic on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Making sure the appropriate purpose is stated (in this case: game development), and appropriate constraints are stated as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would say no, because it's still a technology-recommendation question which we don't currently consider on-topic.

I think a better place to ask this question would be the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) or (as the chat is relatively low-population) a site like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net), which is a more general discussion forum and not hampered by SE's "Q&A" rules and policies.

Comment: Chat is never useful for polls.

Comment: Already found that as on-topic on Software Recomendations. But Chat is a /dev/null for such kind of topics.

Comment: Several people have come into the chat to ask about technology recommendations over the lifetime of the site, it's seemed to have worked for most of them, but YMMV of course. The Software Recommendations site sounds like an excellent place as well.